# Why is AChecker complaining about directional text?

Tags: html, wcag2.0, bidi

I am using the AChecker tool:
https://achecker.ca/checker/index.php

The WCAG test is telling me that I failed Check 271:
https://achecker.ca/checker/suggestion.php?id=270

> **Error**
>   Unicode right-to-left marks or left-to-right marks may be required.

I don’t have any text that would set off the bidirectional algorithm. My whole web page is in English so I am confused on why the WCAG test is complaining about this.

What could be the reason why I am failing this test?

Answer (score 0):

The "potential problems" part of achecker indicate "potential problems" and the error is indicated with a conditionnal statement:

> dir attribute **may** be required to identify changes in text direction.